# Including commas, question marks, exclamation marks in output (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

The goal of this program is to take a user input and convert it to ascii-text.

The code works as it should, but it doesn't include commas, periods, exclamation marks or question marks.

I have tried to include: !, ?, ' and commas, as a seperate list and try to call it in the input. But I wasn't fully sure how to do it.

At the moment I just used a bunch of else-if statements, it works but I feel like there must be a simpler way to fix that. I can't really figure out how. Tips are extremely appreciated!

```py
def asciiToLeet(c):
    l33tLetters = ["@", "8", "(", "|)", "3", "#", "6", "[-]", "|", "_|", "|<", "1", "[]\/[]", "[]\[]", "0", "|D", "(,)", "|Z", "$", "']['",
  "|_|", "\/", "\/\/", "}{", "`/", "2"]
    if c == ' ': return ' '
    elif c == '.': return '.'
    elif c == ',': return ','
    elif c == '?': return '?'
    elif c == '!': return '!'
    elif c == "'": return "'"
    asciiCode = ord(c)
    if asciiCode >= ord('a') and asciiCode <= ord('z'):
        return l33tLetters[asciiCode - ord('a')]
    if asciiCode >= ord('A') and asciiCode <= ord('Z'):
        return l33tLetters[asciiCode - ord('A')]
    return "" 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inputString = input()
    outputString = ""
    for c in inputString:
        outputString += asciiToLeet(c)
    print(outputString)
```

My expectation is for the code to show the output with the punctuations without having to use if-else statements.

Comment: `if c in " .,?!'": return c` perhaps?

Comment: `if c in [" ", ".", ",", "?", "!", "'"]: return c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `return ""` at the end of your method. Thus, if all of your lookups fail, it discards the input character. Instead, do `return c`. This will cause the input character to be returned as-is if the lookups to make it "leet" don't match it.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really solved the problem. I can't thank you enough <3 I even removed the if else statements and it worked. Thank you!